# Проверка hash суммы подгружаемого JS, CSS или PNG

Tags: html, хеширование

В доке для bootstrap заметил странный импорт js и css где как я понял указан hash файла, то есть код:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" 
integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" 
crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

И вопрос в том браузеры учитывают этот параметр и проверяют hash или нет или зависит от браузера?

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=subresource-integrity

Comment: @andreymal да, спасибо, это то что искал.